# Defining a new interface causes "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:". Existing interfaces work fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an iOS app and am using XCode Version 6.3.1 (6D1002).
I have a m file in which I define

```
@interface CustomObject:NSObject {} @end
```

and I try to use in viewDidLoad as

```
CustomObject* obj = [[CustomObject alloc]init];
```

When I run this, I get linkage errors saying

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CustomObject", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ChooseAlbumViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I have similar interfaces defined for other objects and those continue to build, link and run fine. Any new interfaces I'm defining are failing with these linkage errors. I could use some help to figure out what's causing this. I'm new to iOS development so if I'm missing information crucial to figure this out please let me know and I'll add it.

Few flags from my Build Settings that might help -
    `Build Active Architecture Only = YES`
    `Architectures = Standard Architecture armv7 armv64`
    `Valid Architectures = arm64 armv7 armv7s`

Here is the code in which I define the interface and try to use it

```
@interface CustomAlbum : NSObject {

}
@end
@implementation ChooseAlbumViewController
{
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CustomAlbum* a = [[CustomAlbum alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: Make sure  `ChooseAlbumViewController.m` is checked under "Target " for your project's target

Comment: Can you show how you import the `CustomObject`?

Comment: To avoid issues with importing, I've defined the interface in the class that's trying to use it. I've added the first few lines of that .m file to the question

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out, the problem was that I had only defined an interface but had not defined an implementation. Adding

```
@implementation User
@end
```

to the .m file solved the linkage issues.

Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, this happens when your class isn't being compiled into the target you want. Select the .m file that `CustomObject` is in and check the right sidebar. In the first tab, there should be a list of targets. Check ✔️ your current target so that Xcode compiles it.

Comment: To avoid issues with the target, I've defined the interface in the class that is  trying to use it. It still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

while compiling the source file `ChooseAlbumViewController` looks for a corresponding header. The header named `CustomAlbum` doesn't match. This causes the error message.

Comment: Not sure I follow. I do have a ChooseAlbumViewController.h file. I don't see the relation between an interface and the header file since the interface is defined in the .m file. Are you saying I need a separate header filer for CustomAlbum? I don't think that's true since i've already defined and used similar interfaces without placing them in their own header files

Comment: i just meant that the class names after `@interface` and `@implementation` must match